# Design approaches for batch processing of parallel tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi, batch-processing, apache-karaf

I have a batch job that is expected to process around 1k task at a time. And each task roughly takes around 12 - 16 minutes on an average.

In current implementation , all tasks are pushed into a blocking queue. There is a thread that pops a task from this queue and processes it. For task we are using java's executor service for concurrent execution and once all of its sub tasks are processed we mark this task as complete and head to read another task from the queue. We cant optimize task processing time since it makes call to native library and are unaware of what it does internally.

With current implementation we are able to process around 300 task in more than 24 hrs.

I'm looking for appropriate platform or framework that could help to reduce the processing time.

I'm using Java 1.7,OSGI and Apache Karaf as container

PS : The task here is breaking down of certain images ranging from 500 MB - 4 GB into small chunks and storing it into jpeg format

Comment: Do you have 100% cpu load or hdd load at some point?

Comment: yes both CPU and Network(since we are processing from network) show 100% utilization

Comment: over the full 24 hours? If yes then I would assume that the native lib simply takes as long as that.

Comment: I would say throw more resources at it then or replace the lib

Comment: yeah we are looking at how to scale the processing. that's why we are looking at any open source platforms for horizontal scaling (rather than vertical scaling)! Do we have any such good platforms to automate things?

Comment: Maybe OSGi remote services. But there're lots of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For horizontal scaling I would use a messaging system. Simply put all the tasks into a JMS queue. Then start karaf on a cluster of machines and let each listen on the queue. JMS will then automatically feed the processes round robin. So the load will be distributed.